# IP Restriction In IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7

I want to deny all IP address in my iis and allow only one IP.How can I make it in iis in windows 2008 server.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In IIS manager click the server you want to work with. In the features pane click 'Management Service'. When the management service is stopped you can then can then edit the IPv4 Address restrictions.

Take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730889.aspx and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324066

Comment: I am Using IIS 7.There I couldn't find any management services or properties .

Comment: You need to click the Server in the tree view on the left, rather than any of the sites. In the big pane on the right at the bottom there is a section called Management. Management Service is in this section.